# Spring WebClient and JSON array with possible errors in its elements

Tags: json, spring, deserialization, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm trying to fetch a JSON-array of length *n* and deserialize it to *n* objects of type  *RegistryPerson*. This class is from an XSD and is immutable w.r.t. modification. One caveat is that the JSON-array may contain data not accepted by *RegistryPerson*, hence deserialization fails (Error: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize value of type ...). In this instance, the list contains an element with a date string that the serializer doesn't care for.

When deserialization fails, everything fails and the result is empty. With a correct list, I get the expected objects.

My idea is to fetch the JSON, process each entry and deserialize it to *RegistryPerson*. If an entry contains an error, I'll simply drop it and carry on with the next.

```java
List<RegistryPerson> registryPersons = regWebClient //this is the WebClient
            .get().uri(personerUrl(identifikatorer))
            .exchangeToFlux(r -> {
                Flux<RegistryPerson> flux;
                try {
                    log.info("Processing..");
                    flux = r.bodyToFlux(RegistryPerson.class);
                } catch (Exception e) { // e: decoding error
                    log.error("Rotten data!");
                    return Flux.empty();
                }
                return flux;
            })
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage())).onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
            .collectList()
            .flatMap(Mono::just).block();
```

However, it seems like everything is being performed at once, i.e. the *Processing..* is logged only once, even though the JSON has several elements. A list with two correct elements and a list with one correct and one with non-valid data for the class will only generate one log-line.

Considering the *.exchangeToFlux()*, is there a way to make it process element by element, as opposed to the whole list at once?

I don't think the *RegistryPerson* nor the JSON is relevant to post, but it someone is interested in this post and wants to see these, I'll provide.

Comment: I'm at home, trying to reproduce this issue. Strange thing is that the code works flawlessly. I haven't done anything different, yet it processes the JSON element by element and skips element which raises deserialization-error. I'll compare my current code to the above tomorrow (which is at my work-computer) and I'll post and answer if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works (abbreviated for production):

```java
        return regWebClient
            .get().uri(personerUrl(identifikatorer))
            .exchangeToFlux(r -> r.bodyToFlux(RegistryPerson.class))
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage())).onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty()) //If something goes wrong, just return an empty Mono<> after logging the exception.
            .collectList()
            .flatMap(Mono::just).block();
```

The code above seems to do exactly the same, except from the `return Flux.empty()`, however this does not break anything.